# Загрузки Java jdbc drivers в drivermanager при старте tomcat

Tags: java, jdbc

В данный момент пишу веб-приложение, одна из функций которого выполнять SQL запросы по разным базам(баз много, Oracle и MS SQL). 
Базы динамически обновляются и из сервис нэймы беру, с помощью удаленного парсинга серверов, на которых они крутяться и из них уже составляю конекшены. 
Приходиться в связи с чем использовать `drivermanager` и `class.forname`.
Запуск `class.forname` занимает около 12 секунд и драйвер постоянно перерегестрируется.
 
Пытаюсь понять, как можно закоментить `class.forname` и дальше пользоваться драйверменеджером и зарегистрировать в него классы драйвера при старте томката8. 
Датасоры - не вариант, баз слишком много, базы меняются.
Java8, tomcat8, jsp

Comment: DriverManager.getDriver(String url) ? Если у вас в папке lib самого ТС есть необходимые классы, то можно и так их получить

Comment: Да, String = "oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver" ; в либах томката 2 драйвера под 2 Ос, но при get driver - no suitable driver..

Comment: Нет. String - это как раз url. Ну к примеру вот для oracle DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:oracle:thin:")

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало !:))

Comment: оформляю тогда как ответ

Answer (score 1):

1. Необходимо все драйвера подкинуть в папку `lib` в `tomcat`
2. В коде для получения драйвера вызывать уже `DriverManager.getDriver(String url)`, где `url` - начало `url` подключения к БД

**Как пример для oracle**:

```
DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:oracle:thin:")
```

Чтобы посмотреть все доступные драйвера:

```
Enumeration<Driver> e = DriverManager.getDrivers();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
  Object driverAsObject = e.nextElement();
  System.out.println("JDBC Driver=" + driverAsObject);
}
```